# Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js

Tags: angular, dynamic-compilation

I have installed ng-dynamic but cannot proceed to use. i keep on getting this error in console. could not find any fix. tried to refer in different ways in systemjs.config.js file:

'ng-dynamic': 'npm:ng-dynamic/index.js'

'ng-dynamic': 'node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js'

'ng-dynamic': 'https://unpkg.com/ng-dynamic@2.0.0/index.js'

Whats the issue?

ERRORS:

```
 1.GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur

 2.Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as
 _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [] at
 Zone.runTask
 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ =>
 ] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke
 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) []
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur Unable to load transpiler
 to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js
 as "ng-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js at
 XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange]
 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [] at
 Zone.runTask
 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [ =>
 ] at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke
 (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) []
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur Unable to load transpiler
 to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-dynamic/index.js
 as "ng-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It appears to be related to the format of the js file, since it is formatted like typescript and is accompanied by a js.map file. I'm not sure at the moment how to fix this, either.